# Trying to use deployment inside a matrix

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd

Hi I'm making a pipleine in Azure DevOps and I'm trying to use a matrix to access multiple vms in a deployment.
When I try using a deployment inside the job with the matrix, I get this error:
run-qa-deployment-job.yml (Line: 13, Col: 1): Unexpected value 'jobs'

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, or if this is simply not allowed to work?

Here's the template with the matrix:
run-qa-deployment-stages.yml

```
parameters:
- name: EnvironmentName
  displayName: Environment Name
  type: string
  default: "MyEnvironment"

jobs:
- job: GetVMNamesJob
  displayName: "Get VM Names"
  steps:
    - download: 1111
      artifact: "VMNames"
    - task: PowerShell@2
      name: GetVMNamesPowershell
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          $json = Get-Content '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\1111\VMNames\VMNames.json'
          Write-Host $json
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=VMNames;isOutput=true]$json"

- job: DEPLOY_MATRIX_VM
  dependsOn: GetVMNamesJob
  displayName: Deploy VMS
  pool: 
    vmImage: windows-latest  
  strategy:
    matrix: $[ dependencies.GetVMNamesJob.outputs['GetVMNamesPowershell.VMNames'] ]
  steps: 
    - checkout: none
    - template: run-qa-deployment-job.yml
      parameters:
        EnvironmentName: ${{ parameters.EnvironmentName }}
        VMName: $(VMName)
        VMIndex: $(machineIndex)
```

And here's the template with the deployment
run-qa-deployment-job.yml

```
parameters:
- name: EnvironmentName
  displayName: Environment Name
  type: string
  default: "MyEnvironment"
- name: VMName
  displayName: Virtual Machine Name
  type: string
- name: VMIndex
  displayName: Virtual Machine Index
  type: number

jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy_ICP_VM_${{ parameters.VMIndex }}
    dependsOn: 
    displayName: Deploy ICP VM ${{ parameters.VMName }}
    timeoutInMinutes: 0
    environment:
      name: ${{ parameters.EnvironmentName }}.${{ parameters.VMName }}
    workspace:
      clean: all 
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - task: PowerShell@2
              displayName: Temporary
              inputs:
                targetType: 'inline'
                script: |
                  Write-Host "Hello World"
```

Thanks!

Tried making the run-qa-deployment-job.yml just -deployment, and nothing happened.
I've also confirmed that the matrix does work with just a simple text output job.

Answer (score 0):

**Point 1:**

I do not think you can use Job template in steps level. you can refer the docs that. [here is an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops&pivots=templates-includes).

```
# File: templates/jobs.yml
jobs:
- job: Ubuntu
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - bash: echo "Hello Ubuntu"

- job: Windows
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  steps:
  - bash: echo "Hello Windows"

# File: azure-pipelines.yml

jobs:
- template: templates/jobs.yml  # Template reference
```

if you are invoking the job templates, the job template file should be the jobs. the same situation applies to steps.

---

**Point 2:**

you should not use number in passing matrix machineIndex.

---

**my test:**

I have create a sample test for you. **caution about the file locations diff from yours.** (the json location)

VMNames.json

```
{
    "test0":  {
                  "VMName":  "vm0",
                  "machineIndex":  "0"
              },
    "test1":  {
                  "VMName":  "vm1",
                  "machineIndex":  "1"
              }
}
```

run-qa-deployment-stages.yml

```
parameters:
  - name: EnvironmentName
    displayName: Environment Name
    type: string
    default: "MyEnvironment"

jobs:
  - job: GetVMNamesJob
    displayName: "Get VM Names"
    pool:
      vmImage: windows-latest
    steps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        name: GetVMNamesPowershell
        inputs:
          targetType: "inline"
          script: |
            $json = Get-Content '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\strategyMatrix\VMNames.json'
            Write-Host $json
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=VMNames;isOutput=true]$json"

  - job: DEPLOY_MATRIX_VM
    dependsOn: GetVMNamesJob
    displayName: Deploy VMS
    pool:
      vmImage: windows-latest
    strategy:
      matrix: $[ dependencies.GetVMNamesJob.outputs['GetVMNamesPowershell.VMNames'] ]
    steps:
      - checkout: none
      - template: run-qa-deployment-job.yml
        parameters:
          EnvironmentName: ${{ parameters.EnvironmentName }}
          VMName: $(VMName)
          VMIndex: $(machineIndex)
```

deployment run-qa-deployment-job.yml -> be better the name of xx-step.yml

```
parameters:
- name: EnvironmentName
  displayName: Environment Name
  type: string
  default: "MyEnvironment"
- name: VMName
  displayName: Virtual Machine Name
  type: string
- name: VMIndex
  displayName: Virtual Machine Index
  type: string

steps:
- script: |
    echo "env is: ${{ parameters.EnvironmentName }} "
    echo "vmName is: ${{ parameters.VMName }} "
    echo "vmIdex is:  ${{ parameters.VMIndex }} "
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- You should not insert a `deployment`/`job` template into the `steps` section of another `job`;
- `matrix` implementation only works in [jobs.job.strategry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/jobs-job-strategy?view=azure-pipelines); using `matrix` in `deployment` job is not supported;
- In a pipeline, template expression (`${{ parameters }}`) gets processed at compile time, **before** runtime starts; the VM resource in your template that you selected for deployment must be determined at compile time; therefore, we cannot use output variables at runtime to decide which VM resource to be used.

Per your requirements to get the VM resource name in one `job` and then use that dynamic name for `deployment`, you may consider separating the workflow into 2 pipelines, since we are able to output the VM name in the first pipeline (`GetVMNames`) at runtime of first pipeline and then tell the second pipeline (`DeployToSelectedVMs`) to use the selected VM resource at compile time of the second pipeline. Kindly refer to the pipelines below for example.

### VMNames.json

```
[
    {
        "VMName": "E-AZVMAS-WIN11",
        "VMIndex": "vmIndex0"
    },
    {
        "VMName": "E-AZVMAS-WIN2022",
        "VMIndex": "vmIndex1"
    }
]
```

### GetVMNames.yml

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: 1111
    source: 1111-CI

parameters:
- name: EnvironmentName
  displayName: Environment Name
  type: string
  default: "MyEnvironment"

variables:
  TheProjectName: TheProjectName
  pipelineId: 10191
  
jobs:
- job: GetVMNamesJob
  displayName: "Get VM Names"
  pool: 
    vmImage: windows-latest
  steps:
    - checkout: none
      persistCredentials: true
    - download: 1111
    - task: PowerShell@2
      name: GetVMNamesPowershell
      env:
        SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          # Read the content of the JSON file
          $json = Get-Content '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\1111\VMNames\VMNames.json'
          Write-Host VMResources are "$json"

          Write-Host "Trigger Downstream Pipeline - DeployToSelectedVMs:"
          $URL = "$(System.CollectionUri)/TheProjectName/_apis/pipelines/$(pipelineId)/runs?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
          $headers = @{
              'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
              'Authorization' = 'bearer ' + $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN
          }

          $body = @{
              resources = @{
                  repositories = @{
                      self = @{
                          refName = "refs/heads/master"
                      }
                  }
              }
              templateParameters = @{
                  EnvironmentName = "${{ parameters.EnvironmentName }}"
                  VMResources = "$json"
              }
          }

          Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $URL -Headers $headers -Body ($body | ConvertTo-Json )
```

### DeployToSelectedVMs.yml

It uses `${{ each }}` expression to expand deployments jobs in a loop based on the `objects` from the `VMNames.json`.

```
parameters:
- name: EnvironmentName
  default: MyEnvironment
- name: VMResources
  type: object
  default: []

jobs:
- ${{each VM in parameters.VMResources }}:
  - deployment: Deploy_ICP_VM_${{ VM.VMIndex }}
    dependsOn: []
    displayName: Deploy ICP VM ${{ VM.VMName }}
    timeoutInMinutes: 0
    environment:
      name: ${{ parameters.EnvironmentName }}.${{ VM.VMName }}
    workspace:
      clean: all 
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - task: PowerShell@2
              displayName: Temporary
              inputs:
                targetType: 'inline'
                script: |
                  Write-Host "VMName: ${{ VM.VMName }}"
                  Write-Host "VMIndex: ${{ VM.VMIndex }}"
```

[image]

Here are the documents you may check for more details. Hope the workaround helps.

[Expressions - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops)

[Define variables - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax)

[Use runtime and type-safe parameters - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script)